# How to setup VSCode for golang/go cmd module?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

It works well for `std` module ([golang/go](https://github.com/golang/go) root directory) on VSC. However it doesn't work on `cmd` module (opened from `src/cmd` directory). There were no code navigation, symbol search, and even any problems/errors reported.

Version info:

vscode: 1.61.0
vscode-go: v0.28.1

Installed go tools:

gopkgs
go-outline
gotests
gomodifytags
impl
goplay
dlv
dlv-dap
staticcheck
gopls

Comment: What exactly is not working?

Comment: Have you tried to open vscode from the `src/cmd` directory? And I also assume you already followed the instruction here https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/advanced.md#working-on-the-go-source-distribution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Open VSC from `$WORKSPACE/go`. Follow the instruction of https://github.com/golang/tools/blob/master/gopls/doc/advanced.md#working-on-the-go-source-distribution as @hana mentioned:

1. Compile the Go binary. Change working directory to `$WORKSPACE/go/src` and run `./make.bash` (or `./make.bat` for Windows cmd). It will generate the `$WORKSPACE/go/bin` directory.
2. Set `"go.goroot"` to `"${workspaceFolder}"` and install all Go tools required.

Comment: For 2, my preference is the `"go.alternateTools": "$WORKSPACE/go/bin/go"` because using `"go.goroot"` sets `GOROOT` env var, and often that becomes another source of problem.

Comment: Hi, @Hana `"go.alternateTools"` requires an object (available keys are dlv, go, o-outline, gopkgs and gopls). How can I set all of these correctly?

Comment: Oh, sorry my bad. `"go.alternateTools": { "go": "/path/to/your/go/project/bin/binary" }`.